# How to determine the zodiac symbol in R?

Tags: r

I did some statistics today using `Excel` and `R`. Part of the work requires to determine the zodiac symbol according to the date of birth. I did this in Excel:

Sample data:

```
DOB
25-Jan-1985
25-Jul-1983
28-Aug-1982
24-Feb-1984
13-Jan-1985
24-Jan-1982
15-Feb-1984
14-Oct-1983
08-Sep-1984
04-Mar-1983
04-Apr-1984
31-Mar-1985
04-Aug-1984
29-Jan-1984
20-Jul-1984
...
```

Here is the rule to determine zodiac symbols:

```
Dec. 22 - Jan. 19 - Capricorn 
Jan. 20 - Feb. 17 - Aquarius 
Feb. 18 - Mar. 19 - Pisces 
March 20 - April 19 - Aries 
April 20 - May 19 - Taurus 
May 20 - June 20 - Gemini 
June 21 - July 21 - Cancer 
July 22 - Aug. 22 - Leo 
Aug 23 - Sept. 21 - Virgo 
Sept. 22 - Oct. 22 - Libran 
Oct. 23 - Nov. 21 - Scorpio 
Nov. 22 - Dec. 21 - Sagittarius
```

Excel formula:

```
=LOOKUP(--TEXT(A2,"mdd"),{101,"Capricorn";120,"Aquarius";219,"Pisces";321,"Aries";420,"Taurus";521,"Gemini";621,"Cancer";723,"Leo";823,"Virgo";923,"Libran";1023,"Scorpio";1122,"Sagittarius";1222,"Capricorn"})
```

I'm wondering how to do it in `R`? Also `data.table` is great, is it possible to figure it out in `data.table`?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.inside-r.org/node/228950

Comment: @Josh Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data is called dat.

First, convert it to a date format:

```
dat$DOB <- as.Date(dat$DOB, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Then use the `Zodiac` function from `DescTools`, as mentioned by @Josh in the comment:

```
library(DescTools)
dat$Zodiac <- Zodiac(dat$DOB)
dat
```

Comment: `R` is really wonderful -- full of functions, full of surprises. Thank you.